# JavaScript: Make function which work same like find():

Tags: javascript, callback

I need to make function which work same like find(). I try make it but it doesn't work. As I understand, need to make callback function with cycle. And I cannot use another methods for array. Bellow I put code which I make for that time. Thank you for your attention to my problem.

```
const callBack = arr => {
   for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
    if (arr[i] > 3) return arr[i];
   }
}
const copyFind = callback => {
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
callback(arr);
}
copyFind(callBack);
```

Comment: What is an issue of using find?

Comment: Its a task =(, I need make it without find()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function find(array, callback) {
   for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      const isFound = callback.call(array, array[i], i, array)
      if (isFound) return array[i];
   }
}

find([1,2,3,4,5], (item) => item > 3) // 4
```